# インターフェース（動きのあるクラス）の、速さについて質問です。

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで質問があります。

1. この場合、FlyingCircleクラスのインスタンス変数vx,vyはずっと変化しない（例えばFC1の場合は21,11のまま）でしょうか？
2. インスタンスメソッド moveTo()の処理内容
   `if(xpos < 0 && vx < 0 || xpos > 700 && vx > 0) vx = -vx;`
   `if(ypos < 0 && vy < 0 || ypos > 500 && vy > 0) vy = -vy;` について
   xpos<0はわかりますが（円の中心のx座標が0以下になったらという意味？）、vx<0,vx>0の意味がわかりません。(vyも同様）そもそもvx,vyはnewでコンストラクタを呼び出す際に値を決めているので、0以下になったり、0以上になるということがないと思うのですが、この式はどういう意味なのでしょうか？
3. メインクラスの下のCircleクラスやFlyingCircleクラスは、Javaのオブジェクト指向では、なんという名前のクラスでしょうか？

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FlyCircle extends JPanel {
    Circle C1;
    FlyingCircle FC1, FC2, FC3;

    public FlyCircle() {
        setOpaque(false);
        C1 = new Circle(Color.BLUE, 100, 300, 20);
        FC1 = (new FlyingCircle(Color.RED, 100, 100, 25, 21, 11));
        //  FC2 = (new FlyingCircle(Color.GREEN, 100, 100, 15, 21, 11));
        ///  FC3 = (new FlyingCircle(Color.CYAN, 100, 100, 35, 3, 3));
        ///  FC3.moveTo(300, 300); 

        final long tm0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new javax.swing.Timer(30, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                double tm=0.001*(System.currentTimeMillis()-tm0);
                C1.moveTo((int)(150+70*Math.sin(Math.PI*tm*5)),380);

                FC1.moveTo();

                //      FC2.moveTo(width, height, true);
                //      FC3.moveTo(width, height, true);
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        C1.draw(g2); FC1.draw(g2);
        //   FC2.draw(g2);
        //   FC3.draw(g2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame app = new JFrame();
        app.add(new FlyCircle());
        app.setSize(700, 500);
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class Circle{
        Paint pat;
        int xpos, ypos, rad;
        public Circle(Paint p, int x, int y, int r) {
            pat = p; xpos = x; ypos = y; rad = r;
        }
        public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
            g.setPaint(pat);
            g.fillOval(xpos-rad, ypos-rad, 2*rad, 2*rad);
        }
        public void moveTo(int x, int y) {
            xpos = x; ypos = y;
        }
        public int getX() {
            return(xpos);
        }
        public int getY() {
            return(ypos);
        }
        public int getR() {
            return(rad);
        }
        public Paint getPaint() {
            return(pat);
        }
        public void setPaint(Paint p) {
            pat = p;
        }
    }

    static class FlyingCircle{
        Paint pat;
        int xpos, ypos, rad;
        double vx, vy;
        public FlyingCircle(Paint p, int x, int y, int r,
                double vx1, double vy1) {
            pat = p; xpos = x; ypos = y; rad = r; vx = vx1; vy = vy1;
        }
        public void moveTo(int x, int y) {
            xpos = x; ypos = y;
        }
        public void moveTo() {
            xpos += vx; ypos += vy;
            if(xpos < 0 && vx < 0 || xpos > 700 && vx > 0) vx = -vx;
            if(ypos < 0 && vy < 0 || ypos > 500 && vy > 0) vy = -vy;
        }
        public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
            g.setPaint(pat);
            g.fillOval((int)(xpos-rad), (int)(ypos-rad), (int)rad*2, (int)rad*2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.この場合、FlyingCircleクラスのインスタンス変数vx,vyはずっと変化しない（例えばFC1の場合は21,11のまま）でしょうか？

いいえ。
関数`FlyingCircle.moveTo()`内で下記の様に変更されます。

```
        if(xpos < 0 && vx < 0 || xpos > 700 && vx > 0) vx = -vx;
        if(ypos < 0 && vy < 0 || ypos > 500 && vy > 0) vy = -vy;
```

> 2.インスタンスメソッド moveTo()の処理内容
> if(xpos < 0 && vx < 0 || xpos > 700 && vx > 0) vx = -vx;
> if(ypos < 0 && vy < 0 || ypos > 500 && vy > 0) vy = -vy;
> について
> xpos<0はわかりますが（円の中心のx座標が0以下になったらという意味？）、vx<0,vx>0の意味がわかりません。(vyも同様）そもそもvx,vyはnewでコンストラクタを呼び出す際に値を決めているので、0以下になったり、0以上になるということがないと思うのですが、この式はどういう意味なのでしょうか？

おそらく左の壁(xpos=0)に当たるかつ、速度が左方向(vx<0)の場合、反射する（vx=-vx）というような処理でしょう。
同様に右、上、下についても同じ処理をしています。

> 3.メインクラスの下のCircleクラスやFlyingCircleクラスは、Javaのオブジェクト指向では、なんという名前のクラスでしょうか？

CircleクラスやFlyingCircleクラスという名前以外にどういう名前になると思ったんですか？